# Reason for sudden JVM crash

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, jvm

Background : I have a Spring Boot app running on tomcat,and it was running just fine for the past couple of months. Just last week,I added a feature update , wherein I am parsing a considerably large csv file(about 90 mb) ,and storing the csv data in a couple of HashMaps. It takes about 20 sec or so to parse and about 600 mb of space in the JVM once it is loaded.
This parsing and loading happens on startup, i.e exactly when the Spring Boot app is deployed.
Problem is,ever since I've added feature into my app,the JVM crashes sporadically. The app runs fine for a few hours,then crashes. Or the JVM crashes as soon as the app is deployed.This happens atleast 3-4 times in a day , and we are suffering downtime because of it.
Also,I can't seem to find anything in tomcat logs. 
I would appreciate if anyone can point me out in a direction to debug this damn crash.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you attach hs_err* logs?

Answer (score 1):

It is very probably that Linux OOM killer kills your application, because of wrong Xmx setup. You can try to look at dmesg log. `dmesg -T | grep kill` and find a line about killing your app.

Comment: root@ads [~]# dmesg -T | grep kill

[Sun May 22 06:18:49 2016] php invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[Sun May 22 06:18:49 2016]  [<ffffffff8116cebe>] oom_kill_process+0x24e/0x3b0

Comment: @Ranjeet Ranjan, yes my guess is true, you have a problem with the oom-killer, that's why you can't find hs_err logs. First of all, make sure that the -xmx option has a reasonable value.

Comment: I have set Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx5000M  -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'. As of now we have no lead on the tomcat but still it getting crashed.

Comment: @RanjeetRanjan, you need to check logs again, other processes can lead to oom and oom-killer will chose "best" (consuming more memory) process to kill

Comment: @RanjeetRanjan, the output of `dmesg` gives you all the information you need. What I saw in you answer-log placed by your colleague it was either PHP or Java causes oom killer to start killing. You can find some instructions how to deal with oom-killer on the internet. There are lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to attach jProfile to your jvm and analyze the memory usage.Or just execute "kill -3 pid" to generate a heap dump file on a particular interval.The files may help you diagnose memory footprint problems.