# Java Process getting killed without logging

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos5

I have a long running Java process running in CentOs Machine. I have both info and
error logs set-up properly. The process ran for longer time (18+ hours) and disappeared 
all of a sudden. There is no trace of error/exception (OutOfMemoryError/ OutOfDiskSpace  Error). How to figure out what has really happened, as in why and how the process got killed?

```
These are the OS details.
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Are there any standard system logs or commands to figure out? This job is running in a servlet in Tomcat. Tomcat is also going down mysteriously.

Comment: You might want to go through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497680/reason-for-sudden-jvm-crash

Comment: Well I think doesn't help: you need to gather more info from the system. Let the process talk a little more, so you see when it stops, monitor it.... (btw how do you know, that it gets killed?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your process is mostly likely killed because the system runs out of memory. When it happens it first tries to kill short-running processes instead of long running ones. OOM Killer is unlikely to be logged in your application logs.

Check `dmesg` and try to find there info about killing `<java_pid>`.

Here is how "badness" of a task to kill determined in Linux https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html#toc21 :

```
badness_for_task = total_vm_for_task / (sqrt(cpu_time_in_seconds) *
sqrt(sqrt(cpu_time_in_minutes)))
```

Kernel steps through all running tasks.